# Postgresql SQL Select items from table1 based on a condition from table2

Tags: sql, postgresql, conditional-statements

I am trying to select items from table1 which has a child table2 there is a third table3 involved.

```
Select j.ccmasterid, 
(Select sum(i.ccmatpullqty) From table2 i 
 Where i.ccmasterid = j.ccmasterid)  pulled
 from table1 j
INNER JOIN table3 s on j.ccstatus = s.sysstatusid and s.ccopenjob=false
where j.ccmasterid LIKE 'W%' and pulled = 0
```

This generates an error:

> ERROR:  column "pulled" does not exist
>   LINE 6: where j.ccmasterid LIKE 'W%' and pulled = 0

If I take the "**and pulled = 0**" out the the query, it works as one would expect producing a list of records from table1 with the sum of the values in table2 as pulled.

```
ccmasterid    pulled
W106063            0
W100553            9
W100685            1
```

WHAT I can't figure out is how to select based on pulled being 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this query into a subquery, and move WHERE condition to the outer query:

```
SELECT * FROM (
   Select j.ccmasterid, 
   (Select sum(i.ccmatpullqty) From table2 i 
    Where i.ccmasterid = j.ccmasterid)  pulled
    from table1 j
   INNER JOIN table3 s on j.ccstatus = s.sysstatusid and s.ccopenjob=false
   where j.ccmasterid LIKE 'W%'
) x
WHERE  pulled = 0
```

Comment: Thanks. That is it.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid the correlated subquery which runs for *every* row in outer query and not *once* if joining to an aggregate query with `GROUP BY` clause:

```
SELECT j.ccmasterid
FROM table1 j
INNER JOIN table3 s 
    ON j.ccstatus = s.sysstatusid AND s.ccopenjob = false
INNER JOIN
   (SELECT i.ccmasterid, SUM(i.ccmatpullqty) AS pulled
    FROM table2 i 
    GROUP BY i.ccmasterid
   ) AS agg
    ON agg.ccmasterid = j.ccmasterid
WHERE j.ccmasterid LIKE 'W%' AND agg.pulled = 0
```

Even use CTE

```
WITH agg AS
    (SELECT i.ccmasterid, SUM(i.ccmatpullqty) AS pulled
     FROM table2 i 
     GROUP BY i.ccmasterid)

SELECT j.ccmasterid
FROM table1 j
INNER JOIN table3 s 
    ON j.ccstatus = s.sysstatusid AND s.ccopenjob = false
INNER JOIN agg
    ON agg.ccmasterid = j.ccmasterid
WHERE j.ccmasterid LIKE 'W%' AND agg.pulled = 0
```